# Why does socketpair() allow SOCK_DGRAM type?

Tags: linux, sockets, socketpair

I've been learning about Linux socket programming recently, mostly from [this site](http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/manuals/lspe/snode=43.html).

The site says that using the domain/type combination `PF_LOCAL`/`SOCK_DGRAM`...

> Provides datagram services within the local host. Note that this
>   service is **connectionless**, but reliable, with the possible exception
>   that packets might be lost if kernel buffers should become exhausted.

My question, then, is why does `socketpair(int domain, int type, int protocol, int sv[2])` allow this combination, when according to its man page...

> The  socketpair() call creates an unnamed pair of **connected** sockets in
>   the specified domain, of the specified type...

Isn't there a contradiction here?

I thought `SOCK_DGRAM` in the `PF_LOCAL` and `PF_INET` domains implied UDP, which is a connectionless protocol, so I can't reconcile the seeming conflict with `socketpair()`'s claim to create connected sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datagram sockets have "pseudo-connections". The protocol doesn't really have connections, but you can still call `connect()`. This associates a remote address and port with the socket, and then it only receives packets that come from that source, rather than all packets whose destination is the address/port that the socket is bound to, and you can use `send()` rather than `sendto()` to send back to this remote address.

An example where this might be used is the `TFTP` protocol. The server initially listens for incoming requests on the well-known port. Once a transfer has started, a different port is used, and the sender and receiver can use `connect()` to associate a socket with that pair of ports. Then they can simply send and receive on that new socket to participate in the transfer.

Similarly, if you use `socketpair()` with datagram sockets, it creates a pseudo-connection between the two sockets.

Comment: Using `connect()` on a datagram socket also enables use of `recv()` and `send()` on that socket, instead of having to use `recvfrom()` and `sendto()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think you can use `recv()` on an unconnected socket, you just won't know where it came from. But you're right about `send()`.